# How to move a topic from one broker to another broker in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I first tried to see if I can create a topic in a particular broker. But looks like this is not possible. Even if I mention the broker host in the bootstrap

```
    admin_client = AdminClient({
    "bootstrap.servers": "xxx1.com:9092,xxx2.com:9092"
})

futmap=admin_client.create_topics(topic_list)
```

The program is arbitrarily picking up one of the 5 brokers that I have as the leader broker for the topic. I am trying to understand why it happens like this.

I am also trying to see if I can reassign the topic leader to another broker. I know it may be possible through the kafka-reassign-partitions command line script, but I wanted to do it programmatically using python and confluent-Kafka package. Is it possible to do this programmatically. I did not find the reassign partition function in the ADMIN class of confluent-Kafka package

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally got the solution for this, the documentation of the confluent Kafka python package is not adequate for this. But one good thing about open source is that you can read the code and figure out. So, to create the topic in a particular broker, I had to code the create topic code as below. Please note that I have used replica_assignment instead of replication_factor. These two are mutually exclusive. If you use the replication_factor, the partitions will be assigned by Kafka, you can control the assignment through replica_assignment. However, I am sure that this will get re-assigned in case of a rebalancing/re-assigning of partitions. But that can also be handled through the on_revoke event. But for now, this works for me.

```
def createTopic(admin_client,topics):
    #topic_name=topics
    topic_name = ['rajib1_test_xxx_topic']
    replica_assignment = [[262, 261]]
    topic_list = [NewTopic(topic, num_partitions=1, replica_assignment=replica_assignment) for topic in topic_name]
futmap=admin_client.create_topics(topic_list)
# Wait for each operation to finish.
for topic, f in futmap.items():
    try:
        f.result()  # The result itself is None
        print("Topic {} created".format(topic))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to create topic {}: {}".format(topic, e))
#return futmap
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` tool that comes with Kafka to change the replicas of one topic to another broker.

For example, if you want to have your (in this example single-replicated, and single-partitioned) topic "test" be located on broker "1", you can first define a plan (named replicachange.json):

```
{
"partitions":
  [{"topic": "test", "partition": 0,
    "replicas": [
       1
    ]
  }],
"version":1
}
```

and then execute it using:

```sh
kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --execute \
--reassignment-json-file replicachange.json
```